# Get all the Ad post from active campaign Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I am looking for API, where in I can get all the Ad post from active campaign Facebook using API.

I have checked all the documentations, however, I couldn't find what I am looking for.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Vishal, what documentation did you check? Getting Ad Post is quite simple:

Do a GET request with your AD ID to get its name (for debugging) and Creative ID, like documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup#read-ad). Example:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/120330000079475610?fields=id,creative,name&access_token=`
You'll get smth like this in response.

[image: AD's endpoint response]

Then request `effective_object_story_id` from you Creative ID like this: `https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/120330000079470010?fields=id,name,effective_object_story_id`. Here's where you'll get your post ID, which is `effective_object_story_id`. 
[image]
It's very well documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/)

Then either use this POST ID to access your post on FB page like this: `https://facebook.com/442997169177181_1903716809771869/

Or get data from it programmatically doing another call to FB Marketing API:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/442997169177181_1903716809771869?fields=id,call_to_action,message,full_picture,child_attachments`. Post's specification is also very detailed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post)

The response might look differently depending on the amount of data in the post and the amount of data you've requested:
[image]

If you carefully read `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis/` all the answers are there.